# Wrong output display With Structures

Tags: c, struct

I 'm trying to execute the following structure in a C program but it's not working. It does not print the given values correctly.

```
  #include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
struct book
{
char name;
int page;
float price;
};
struct book b1, b2, b3;
clrscr();

printf("\n 1st data \n");
scanf("%c%f%d",&b1.name,&b1.price,&b1.page);
printf("\n 2nd data");
scanf(" %c%f%d",&b2.name,&b2.price,&b2.page);
printf("\n3rd data");
scanf("%c%f%d",&b3.name,&b3.price,&b3.page);

printf("%c%f%d",b1.name,b1.price,b1.page);
printf("%c%f%d",b2.name,b2.price,b2.page);
printf("%c%f%d",b3.name,b3.price,b3.page);

getch();
return 0;
}
```

Every time I run the above code, I get different output.. one of them is::
    ....output....

```
data
p
1
2.2
s
2
3.3

p0.1000002.1.00000022015s-?.<00000000000000000000000000000e+15315872
```

Comment: `scanf("%c%f%d"` --> `scanf(" %c%f%d"`, b3 : page <-> price.

Comment: You need spaces and newlines in the `printf` to make the output more readable, for example `printf("%c %f %d\n",...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After giving the second input , the input buffers might get full and hence its not accepting the 3rd input . try using fflush(stdin) after every input .

Answer (score 0):

What?  You are getting erroneous program behavior and you have not checked a single return value?  For the scanf(3), for instance?

Comment: I tried after commenting the 2nd and 3rd scanf and printf still it is giving wrong result...even after providing nextline and all that stuff..Actually it is not even asking for third parameter..??                                                              the output was like :                                                                                                     data                                                                                                                              input::   p    12.11          output::   p     1000.00000   3859

Answer (score 0):

So, in your scanf you are asking for "float" then "decimal integer", but in your sample you seem to be passing integer then float as what you are putting into stdin (see the ouput as you pasted in your question -- c, d, f; not c, f, d). Also, "Oldest Software Guy" is right -- you need to check your return codes (so that this kind of thing doesn't happen), and most would probably recommend that you use "sscanf" and "fgets" as a safer alternative, especially when you start trying to expand your "name" to something more than a single "char".

Comment: thanks @shooper,,,now i have edited the program..but still it is not accepting the third input....output is like:                                                        ist data :  p  1.11  1                                                                                                  2nd data: w 2.22 2                                                                                               3rd data : s                                                                                                                          p 1.11 oooo1    w 2.22 00002    0.00000021507